# Referencing Results of Subquery A in Subquery B of UNION Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to get rows from a table based on the values of other rows from the same table (which I also need in the output).
I'm looking to do the equivalent of the below:

```
SELECT a.id,a.col1,a.col2 FROM tbl a WHERE col1 = @col
UNION
SELECT b.id,b.col1,b.col2 FROM tbl b WHERE b.col2 IN (SELECT a.col1)
UNION
SELECT c.id,c.col1,c.col2 FROM tbl c WHERE c.col1 IN (SELECT b.col1)
```

or

```
(SELECT id,col1,col2 FROM tbl WHERE col1 = @val) a
UNION
SELECT id,col1,col2 FROM tbl b WHERE b.col2 IN (SELECT col1 FROM a)
UNION
SELECT id,col1,col2 FROM tbl c WHERE c.col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM b)
```

But both of these are not allowed. Is there some way to achieve this that avoid tediously recursive statements when extended, like the functional statement below:

```
SELECT * FROM #tbl WHERE col1 = @val
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tbl WHERE col2 = (SELECT col1 FROM #tbl WHERE col1 = @val)
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tbl WHERE col1 = (SELECT col1 FROM #tbl WHERE col2 = (SELECT col1 FROM #tbl WHERE col1 = @val))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d332344fb44a9640318e403cdd4d291)

Comment: lookup recursive ctes

Comment: You can join a table to itself using inner join and an alias as the table name.  LIke Select * From tableName A inner join tableName B  on A.ID = B.ID  both are the same table but using the alias A and B you can use both tables in the same select

Comment: Have you tried self joining the tables?

Comment: @Brad Wouldn't that limit the table? I'm trying to get the row where A.ID = $id and also the row where B.ID = A.ID. Wouldn't joining on A.ID=B.ID prevent me from also getting A.Id=$id ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
with cte as (
      SELECT a.id, a.col1, a.col2
      FROM tbl a
      WHERE col1 = @col
      UNION ALL
      SELECT b.id, b.col1, b.col2
      FROM tbl b JOIN
           cte
           ON b.col2 = cte.col1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You might want `select distinct` in the outer query or `union` in the inner one.

The query itself might be more complicated if your relationships have cycles.